# in PHP, loop through all xml nodes and subnodes using simplexml_load_file & foreach

Tags: php, xml

[Given this XML document](http://puu.sh/iPHyp/5991167dfd.xml)

My code:

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $table = array();
    foreach ($xml->entry as $item) {
        foreach ($item->summary->div->blockquote as $block) {

                $element = array();
                $element['title'] = $block->p;
                $element['updated'] = strtotime($item->updated, time());
                $table[$element['updated']] = $element;

        }
    }
```

I want to insert all "p" values of the "blockquote" node and put them into an array. But it only gets the last "blockquote" node, not all.

I get this:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line foreach ($item->summary->div->blockquote as $block) {
```

I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of code:

```
$element['updated'] = strtotime($item->updated, time());
```

Seems to be always the same for all the elements and that may be overriding all the array.

Your `$item` seems to be always the same inside your second loop.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me a lot of time sir!

Comment: I did mark it as "accepted" answer. However, it requires me 15 reputation points to upvote it as well. Which I don't have yet. Thanks again!